How to get groups of rows bounded by specific values in Pandas?
Data
I have data which resembles the following:
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ["start", ""],
        ["data", 10],
        ["data", 11],
        ["stop", ""],

        ["start", ""],
        ["data", 20],
        ["data", 21],
        ["stop", ""],
    ],
    columns=["type", "value"],
)

    type value
0  start      
1   data    10
2   data    11
3   stop      
4  start      
5   data    20
6   data    21
7   stop      

Goal
My goal is to iterate over plain lists of data, as bounded by start and stop:
[10, 11]
[20, 21]

To do this, I would like to be able to iterate over groups of dataframes which are located by these specific values in specific columns.
Attempt
I can make this work by iterating:
def iter_groups(df):
    start_idx = None
    for idx, row in df.iterrows():
        if row["type"] == "start":
            assert start_idx is None
            start_idx = idx 
            continue
        if row["type"] == "stop":
            assert start_idx is not None
            yield df.iloc[start_idx : idx+1]
            start_idx = None

But this is, unsurprisingly, quite slow. How can I do this using Pandas methods?
Simplification
I think it is safe to assume that there are never any rows between the stop of one group and the start of the next group.

IIUC, you can do:
df.groupby((df["type"].eq("start")).cumsum())["value"].agg(lambda x: x[1:-1])

Explanation:
df["type"].eq("start") gives:


0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5    False
6    False
7    False

When we do cumsum() over it we get:
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    2
5    2
6    2
7    2

As you see at each "True" we get a new group. Now if we groupby and agg the list getting the second to last (excluding) we get the list of elements that we are looking for.
Output:
type
1    [10, 11]
2    [20, 21]


IIUC, you can use search for starts/stops indices and use zip():
start = df.index[df["type"].eq("start")]
stop = df.index[df["type"].eq("stop")]

for start, stop in zip(start, stop):
    print(df.loc[start:stop])

Prints:
    type value
0  start      
1   data    10
2   data    11
3   stop      

    type value
4  start      
5   data    20
6   data    21
7   stop      


Boom. 12x speedup!

Wondering what you get using groupby in case you used it.

You can try following:
import numpy as np

# find indicies of "stop" and + 1 for inclusiveness
# [:-1] eliminates last element to not have empty split
indicies = (df[(df["type"]=="stop")].index + 1)[:-1]

np.array_split(df, indicies)

